# AWS EC2 rotate IPs for outgoing requests

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running ubuntu server that also is running a nodejs app.

I was wondering if its possible, to rotate the EC2 outgoing IP address on every outgoing request the node js app makes?

Right now it is using the same elastic IP everytime. I am looking for a way to rotate IP addresses for every outgoing request. Is that even possible? I could not find a solution reading the aws docs. MAybe I am missing the correct term for that desired behavior.

Comment: You would need to pass the requests through other EC2 instances with public IPs. There is no native way to do this.

Comment: People who ask for such capabilities are normally attempting to scrape websites in violation of the target website's Terms & Conditions. We do not encourage such activities. What is your particular use-case?

Comment: You can not make assumptions without evidence. I dont try to do anything not legal I just want to request an API from the same vps instead of having to host multiple for the same task.